# Compare objects by size of a Set attribute, with empty Set being left at the end of the sorted list

Tags: java, enums, compare, comparator

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private  private Set<MyEnum> enums;

    //getter and setter methods..
}

public enum MyEnum {

    A(1, "..."),
    B(2, "...");

    private int value;
    private String description;

    private MyEnum(int value, String description){
        ....
    }
}
```

How can I compare two User instance, first by enums attribute and then by name?
It's possible when we have a enum set, instead of a single value?

Comment: Yes, you can have a Set of enums. You are already using it. How exactly do you intend to compare a set of enums?

Comment: You want to compare for equality only? or do you want to be able to sort them?

Comment: @Bentaye I have a list of User and I need to order it, first by enums set attribute (increasing order by size) and then by name. I don't know if you understand what I mean..

Comment: @Dave so ordering by the number of elements in the set is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Bentaye, yes. I tried something like `Integer o1Size = o1.getEnums().size(); Integer o2Size = o2.getEnums().size(); int compare = o1Size.compareTo(o2Size); if(compare==0){return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());} return compare;` but not works

Comment: @Dave You should rename your question to something like `Compare objects by size of a Set attribute`. The fact that it is Enums is irrelevant, could be anything in the Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Sorting by enum set size, then by name. Leaving users with empty enums for the end:

I'd implement a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
class UserComparator implements Comparator<User> {
  @Override
  public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
    int compResult = Integer.compare(u1.getEnums().size(), u2.getEnums().size());
    if(compResult == 0)
      compResult = u1.getName().compareTo(u2.getName());
    return compResult;
  }
```

Then use the List [sort(Comparator c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method:

```
User u1 = new User();
u1.setName("Sarah");
u1.setEnums(Collections.emptySet());
User u2 = new User();
u2.setName("Bob");
u2.setEnums(Collections.emptySet());
User u3 = new User();
u3.setName("Peter");
u3.setEnums(EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B));
User u4 = new User();
u4.setName("Nicolas");
u4.setEnums(EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B));
User u5 = new User();
u5.setName("Paul");
u5.setEnums(EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A));

List<User> users = Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3, u4, u5);
users.sort(new UserComparator());

// Then split the list and move the users with empty enums at the end
List<User> sortedNonEmptySetUsers = users.stream()
    .filter(u -> !u.getEnums().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<User> sortedEmptySetUsers = users.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getEnums().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
sortedNonEmptySetUsers.addAll(sortedEmptySetUsers);

List<User> sortedUsers = sortedNonEmptySetUsers;
```

orders this way

```
Paul | [A]
Nicolas | [B, A]
Peter | [B, A]
Bob | []    
Sarah | []
```

Comment: That's odd, because I tested the code I provided. Are the users in my example sorted correctly as you want them?

Comment: @Dave I think this answer works and if you say this doesn't work, you should add some sample input and expected output to your question. @Bentaye I suggest using `EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B)` for better performance, but in any case your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Cheers! I changed to `EnumSet.of` it's lot nicer as well.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. Code works. But, in case user has empty enums set? Should I order in descending order?

Comment: @Dave Users with empty enum sets will be first. I added one in my example

Comment: @Bentaye, yes. But I decided to show user with empty enum for last. I should use descending order. Right?

Comment: @Dave I edited my answer, now sorting by enum set size, then by name. Leaving users with empty enums for the end, also sorted by name.

Comment: @Dave also edit your question to state that you want the empty enum sets being left at the end of the sorted list, because it is not said.

Comment: @Bentaye, thank you! Debugging on sortedUsers I see the users ordered like your example above. But, when I display that list in the page, the first users are always those wtih empty enums.. I don't know, It's like the foreach  on my page does not considerer the order.

Comment: The problem could be DataTable js plugin, which I use for format the html table. However, that's not the point of this thread. Thank you again!

Comment: @Dave could be a typo also if you display `users ` instead of `sortedUsers `. Please accept my answer if it works, cheers!

Comment: Yes, it's datatable plugin.